# Pointer to stored specific memory address

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I have memory location address in a txt file. I want to read the address from the file and use the value stored at that address. Here's what I've done:

```
char line[10];
FILE *f;
f=fopen("p:\\address.txt", "r");
fgets(line,10,f);
```

The file contains the address 0x12ff30. I have stored this in the char array line. The address contains a double value (8 bytes from 0x12ff30). Now how do I create and use a pointer to get the value stored at that address?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want to do?  Generally speaking, you can't access arbitrary memory locations and get meaningful behaviour.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth
Hey! Actually I am running another software which writes data into this memory location real-time. So I'm pretty sure I want to access this location and get that value :)

Comment: You really don't want to do this. If your programs share memory space then there are MUCH better ways to get the pointer there, say, a global variable? At the very least you need to look into IPC http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication such as shared memory. PLEASE don't use the file system as a method of communicating between processes!...

Comment: @user2438252: Hmm.  On most systems, two independent programs will have completely different address spaces, due to [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).  So an address in one program makes no sense in the other program.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth exactly, exactly. About 3 weeks ago I remember somebody wanting to redirect a pointer into and out-of an iostream in C++. We had the same conversation. The pointer literally makes no sense once it leaves the program!

Answer (score 5):

Please do not do this. Please use IPC, that is, inter-process communication.

If you have two processes on virtually ANY modern computer system, they will have their own virtual address spaces. A pointer in one process DOES NOT make sense in some other process.

I recommend that you need to look into using some method of IPC such as shared memory or a message queue, please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication for some links. There are many methods available. You should use this to move the double value around, not a pointer to it. If both programs need concurrent access to that double then you need to think about how you are going to synchronise it anyway.

PLEASE please please don't use the filesystem for IPC. It is really a terrible idea.

Comment: Hey! After posting this I have realized the inter process limitation of a pointer. Thank you very much for pointing that out. One last doubt was if using malloc() would also result in the same thing?

Comment: Also, could you direct me to some helpful tutorials/examples of using shared memory for inter process communication? Thank you.

Comment: This looks ok - http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html. I have no idea what your respective programs do and so I don't know if shared memory is right for you or not. I usually use more of a message passing scheme for communicating between processes - in that case I would use a message queue or TCP/UDP sockets - the advantage of TCP/UDP is that the two processes can be on physically separate machines, but TCP and UDP each have their own pros and cons. (Many problems in life are those of tradeoffs, there are often no right answers!)

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose there be `int` value in that address. Also Let us suppose the address is accessable [when you read the file another time the address may not be valid ] and it will not crash.
Then,

```
void *p;
sscanf(line, "%p", &p);   
double value = *(double *)p;

//use value for other operations.
```

Comment: You're scanning into a `double`?

Comment: I won't give you a -1 instantly but your answer has the following problems: the `%x` format specifier expects an `unsigned int` argument, not an `unsigned long`. the `%p` specifier (and a `void *`) would be more appropriate. You're also not dereferencing the pointer correctly, instead setting `value` to contain a pointer to `p`.

Comment: @Hasturkun you could edit my answer or give your own answer if you could.

Comment: @Hasturkun Then it could be `value = (int) *k` directly na.

Comment: Done. I tend to comment rather than edit when a post is fresh and could be improved by its owner, or when I think something should be clarified. This also helps me avoid edit wars :P

Comment: Bloody hell, you can't de-reference a void pointer. Can people editing this please try their code in a C compiler?

Comment: You can't dereference a `void *`, what would its value be? (also, I'm done editing this post.)

Comment: The question asks how to get the value of the double, not the int. The last line should thus be `double value = *(double*)p;`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to convert a string with hex value to a int??
I have this example

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"stdlib.h"
int main()
{
    char buff[] = "0x12ff30";
    int num = strtol(buff,NULL,16);
    printf("%x\n", num);  // this is 12ff30

    return 0;
```

}

So, you can try this.

```
char line[10];
FILE *f;
f=fopen("p:\\address.txt", "r");
fgets(line,10,f);
int address = strtol(line,NULL,16);
```